# non-blocking network address resolution (gethostbyname or getaddrinfo)?

Tags: c, linux, dns, network-programming

Using a classic nsswitch.conf configuration :

```
hosts:      files dns
```

Trying to resolve a name using **gethostbyname** (or **getaddrinfo**) could take a while if the DNS does not answer (or is badly configured).

Is there a way to configure a timeout in nsswitch.conf or use an alternative api that manage a timeout ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is [getaddrinfo_a](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo_a), but it is <strike>Linux-specific</strike> GNU glibc specific. Alternatively, you can spawn a thread and call getaddrinfo in it. Don't use gethostbyname in a thread, as it is not [thread-safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety).

Comment: gethostbyname() is not thread-safe?  How then is it useable at all?

Comment: `gethostbyname()` returns a pointer to a struct, and this struct may be overwritten by later calls. If you have multiple threads calling gethostbyname, the struct in one thread may be overwritten by another thread. It is not safe to call this function multiple times in different threads, so it is not [thread safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety).

Comment: @MartinJames You're correct, **it is thread safe**. [MSDN gethostbyname](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738524%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): "allocated internally by the Winsock DLL from **thread local storage**" "...Otherwise, the return value will be overwritten by subsequent gethostbyname or gethostbyaddr **calls on the same thread**."

Comment: @parrowdice The question is tagged [tag:linux], if you check the man page of [gethostbyname](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gethostbyname.3.html), it tells you "gethostbyname()    │ Thread safety │ MT-Unsafe race:hostbyname env locale". Note that it says *MT-Unsafe*, which stands for not thread safe

Comment: Well there is also `gethostbyname_r` which is thread-safe. But `gethostbyname*` are all obsolete in favor of `getaddrinfo`.