# why libuv do DNS request by multiple thread

Tags: node.js, dns, libuv

Sometimes my service send large diffirence hostname url all time,  I will re-build my docker container,The container is restarted at the same time，some http request will fail：

```
events.js:154
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.videojj.com www.videojj.com:80
at errnoException (dns.js:26:10)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:77:26)
```

I'm not sure the reason, I know DNS,File operation by multiple thread in libuv. I'm confused why DNS request can't use IO-multiplexing mechanism in libuv

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned and according to the [documentation](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/threadpool.html#threadpool) (emphasis mine):

> libuv provides a threadpool which can be used to run user code and get notified in the loop thread. **This thread pool is internally used to run all file system operations, as well as getaddrinfo and getnameinfo requests**.

The [`uvbook`](https://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/threads.html) gives some other hints about that:

> Threads are used internally to fake the asynchronous nature of all of the system calls. libuv also uses threads to allow you, the application, to perform a task asynchronously that is actually blocking, by spawning a thread and collecting the result when it is done.

So, back to your question:

> why DNS request can't use IO-multiplexing mechanism in libuv

It is due to the fact that fs operations and (let me say) *DNS requests* are blocking system calls. Therefore they would defeat the asynchronous nature of libuv and force the loop to a stall if executed on the main thread. There is no way but to launch them on a separate thread to keep the loop up and running until the job is done.

Note that there exist also non blocking versions of `getaddrinfo` and `getnameinfo` but they are not portable, so libuv cannot use them all the way.
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22013421/4987285) on SO for more details.

Comment: thx for you reply, i just want to know why DNS request is a blocking operation.

Comment: @bugall You asked something different indeed. Anyway, they are synchronous by design and they have asynchronous counterparts (that are not portable unfortunately). Libuv can do nothing but to put them on threads. That's all.

Comment: @bugall: the API for DNS is blocking, at least in POSIX. (libuv tries to stay close to POSIX; in case of DNS you probably can't even get asynchronicity in some other simple way than via threads/processes.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, we need to know the host IP address before send the request, thus, both the send request and the DNS request must be synchronized, because the IO-Multiplexing in libuv working on the master thread,It's foolish to put the sync operation on the main thread,so DNS request use thread-pool.